# Как инициализировать vector<char> строкой?

Tags: c++, строки, vector, char

Есть ли возможность сделать инициализацию `vector<char>` из строки одной строкой кода?
Я делаю так:

```
vector<char> vec;
string str = "To travel you need a wish and your passport";
for (auto it : str)
{
    vec.push_back(it);
}
```

Но хотелось бы узнать более изящный способ.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
string str = "To travel you need a wish and your passport";
vector<char> vec(str.begin(),str.end());
```

Годится?

Можно также

```
vector<char> vec(begin(str),end(str));
```

или, еще лучше,

```
vector<char> vec(cbegin(str),cend(str));
```

Эти варианты (`begin/end` и `cbegin/cend`, но не `str.begin()` и `str.end()`) сработают и для предложенного @Abyx

```
constexpr char str[] = "...";
```

но в этом случае нужно не забывать о том, что в `str` входит и завершающий нулевой символ, который тоже окажется в векторе.

Comment: @Abyx Тут можно прибегнуть к `vector<char> v(begin(str),end(str));` - только учесть, что в вектор будет внесен и нулевой завершающий символ...

Comment: @Abyx Видите ли, я не уверен, что так нужно указывать в ответе. Объяснюсь :) Если вы работаете со `string`, то понятно, чт*о* вы подразумеваете под *строкой*. Если со строкой в стиле C - то этот завершающий нулевой символ может быть существенным, и отбрасывать его просто так я бы не стал. Это уже дело автора конкретного кода. Кроме того, под рукой может оказаться *пустой* массив...

Comment: @Harry, благодарю!

Comment: @Abyx, благодарю!

Comment: Разве `begin(str)` не сработает для варианта @Abyx?

Comment: @alexolut Почему не сработает? Сработает, конечно. Под "вариантом" я понимаю не конкретно `cbegin()`, а вызов свободных функций, а не членов.

Comment: Т.е. надо читать не "Этот вариант сработает", а "Эти варианты сработают" имея ввиду `std::begin` и `std::cbegin`, а не только `std::cbegin`?

Comment: @alexolut Теперь никаких неоднозначностей нет?